# Error message when loading into Ubuntu 18.04 /.xprofile

Tags: boot, dual-boot, touchpad, touchegg

When I boot up Ubuntu I get this error message. It has been working perfectly for a little while now on a dual boot setup with windows 10. I installed touchegg and immediately after I got this error message when prompted to restart ubuntu. I figured it was touchegg as it was booting with ubuntu at the same time. I used the recovery terminal to autoremove it, but still get this error. I can't find the same error online. I can't use the mouse/touchpad/keyboard/any input. What do I do to fix it? Thanks a lot.

Picture: [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzhLE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove .xprofile in your home directory. Alternatively, remove the lines that the system complains about (1-7 in your case), but I doubt that you need .profile at all.